# Solr Text field and String field - different search behaviour

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solrnet

I am working on Solr 4+.

I have several fields into my solr schema with different solr field types.

Does the search on text field and string field differs?

Because I am trying to search on string field (which is a copy field of few facet fields) which does not work as expected. The destination string field is indexed and stored both.

However, when I change destination field which a text field (only indexed), it works fine.

Can you suggest why this happens? What is exactly the difference between text and string fields in solr in respect to searches?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`TextFields` usually have a tokenizer and text analysis attached, meaning that the indexed content is broken into separate tokens where there is no need for an exact match - each word / token can be matched separately to decide if the whole document should be included in the response.

`StrFields` cannot have any tokenization or analysis / filters applied, and will only give results for exact matches. If you need a StrField with analysis or filters applied, you can implement this using a `TextField` and a `KeywordTokenizer`.

Answer (score 0):

A general text field that has reasonable, generic cross-language defaults: it tokenizes with StandardTokenizer,      removes stop words from case-insensitive "stopwords.txt"    (empty by default), and down cases.  At query time only, it     also applies synonyms.

The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

The fields that the Solr model defines by default are very different.

Without using **`tokenization`** or other processes, a string saves a word or sentence as precisely as it is. frequently helpful for facetting, for example, storing exact matches.

Tokenization and secondary processing (such as lower-casing, etc.) are usually handled by text. useful in any situation where we **need to match a sentence's partial.**

If both fields have the example `"This is a sample sentence"` indexed, we need to look for that precise content. For a hit in the text field, searching for `sample` or even samples with stemming enabled may be sufficient. "`This is a sample sentence"` to get a hit in the string field.