# Lucene Phrase Query not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a String `address = "456 SOME STREET";`

which I have to search in Lucene, I have created the index for this

```
StringField address = new StringField(Constants.ORGANIZATION_ADDRESS, address,Field.Store.YES);
```

And I am using Phrase Query to search this String using below Code

```
String[] tokens = address.split("\\s+");
PhraseQuery addressQuery = new PhraseQuery(Constants.ORGANIZATION_ADDRESS, tokens);
finalQuery.add(addressQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

But its not giving me any result,I have tried TermQuery as well but that is also not working. Would really appreciate any help because I have tried many options now and I am unable to figure out whats wrong

I have  also tried below
For Indexing :

```
doc.add(new StringField(Constants.ORGANIZATION_ADDRESS, address,Field.Store.YES));
```

Search using Term Query :

```
fullAddressExact= fullAddressExact.toLowerCase();
TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term(Constants.ORGANIZATION_ADDRESS,fullAddressExact));
finalQuery.add(tq, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Even this doesnt give any result. My intention to get the exact match

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `TextField`, not `StringField` when indexing the documents.

`StringField` stores the string as is, without breaking it into tokens, so in your example the index will contain `"456 SOME STREET"`. Only a `TermQuery` with this term will retrieve it (or a `PrefixQuery`).

`TextField` is the standard field when indexing text, it splits the text into tokens (using a Tokenizer) and indexes the words separately, in your example, `456`, `SOME`, `STREET` can all be used to find the document.
Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752958/solr-text-field-and-string-field-different-search-behaviour) (a bit old, but relevant).

Comment: I need a exact match for String "456 SOME STREET" so should I use TemQuery and StringField ? Although I didnt get result for that as well.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the code, I cant find what I am missing.

Comment: Seems correct... try to remove the `toLowerCase()`, the analyzer should take of that, not you.